# VBA - Loop Through Tabs, Find Header by Name, Replace Values

Tags: vba, for-loop

I have 4 tabs in a workbook that I would like to

- loop through,
- find the header "ClaimName", which resides in different location IF it exists at all,
- and then replace the values "Claim1Score", "Claim2Score", "Claim3Score", "Claim4Score" with "Claim 1", "Claim 2" ... etc.

I am rusty with vba.

I have found similar questions around, but cannot seem to quite get them to work out.

Comment: Replace "Claim12Score" with "Claim 2"? Please edit if you've made a typo, specificity is important :)

Comment: [CTRL]+[H] = Find & Replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codes on this string are very helpful. I ended up doing the following:

```
    'find "ClaimName" and replace values to match template format
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet, R As Range
     For Each sh2 In b1.Sheets
      Set R = sh2.Cells.Find("ClaimName", , xlValues, xlWhole)
     If R Is Nothing Then
         GoTo Nx
     Else
         sh2.Range(R, sh2.Cells(sh2.Rows.Count, R.Column).End(xlUp)).Replace "Score", "", xlPart
         sh2.Range(R, sh2.Cells(sh2.Rows.Count, R.Column).End(xlUp)).Replace "Claim", "Claim ", xlPart
     End If
Nx:
     Next sh2
```

if there is anything to make it more elegant, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

An inelegant but working solution is just to check every range on every tab for every entry required - it's not nice but it'll work. I've given you the components below to piece together so that it's a learning experience along the way!

It will be quick enough over 4 tabs if they're not massive but you can improve the solution by checking only relevant ranges e.g. just a header row instead of the whole sheet.

There are a few different components here:

- Looping through tabs:

  ```
  Dim TempWs as Worksheet
  For Each TempWs in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

      [ Code ]

  Next TempWs
  ```
- Checking for "ClaimName" in each tab - this goes in place of "[Code]" above:

  ```
  Dim TempRng as Range
  For Each TempRng in TempWs.UsedRange

       If TempRng.Value = "ClaimName" Then

            [More code]

       End If

  Next TempRng
  ```
- Replacing text - this goes in place of "[More code]" above

  ```
  Dim TempRng2 as Range
  For Each TempRng2 in TempWs.UsedRange

       If TempRng2.Value = "Claim1Score" Then

            TempRng2.Value = "Claim 1"

       End If

  Next TempRng2

  Exit For 'To abandon checking for 'ClaimName' as this is no longer required
  ```

You will need a further loop which goes outside the "[More code]" for loop and then insider the [More code] For loop, you use the below to construct the input and output. So for the number of claims your dealing with, you can parameterise the number and then Exit For as well after you make the replacement e.g.

```
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 to 10

          If...... = "Claim" & i & "Score"

                  = "Claim " & i

          End If

    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to many cells (Range A1:Z1 inside the code), you could loop through them:

```
Sub replaceClaim()
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each cel In ws.Range("A1:Z1")
            If cel.Text Like "Claim#Score" Then
                cel.Value = "Claim " + Mid(cel.Text, 6, 1)
            ElseIf cel.Text Like "Claim##Score" Then
                cel.Value = "Claim " + Mid(cel.Text, 6, 2)
            End If
        Next cel
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Works for "Claim0Score" to "Claim99Score". Else you have to modify :-)